# DataTable - Radiobutton: how obtain data of selected row

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am working on a register application for new users. On one page user can choose free term. For this purpose I am using PrimeFaces DataTable - Radiobutton. I have been following [PrimeFaces ShowCase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf).

Maybe that now I have a little bit stupid question, but **how can I obtain data, e.g. c_id, of selected row?** I really can't resolve it.
For example this try doesn't work:

```
public String selectData() {
        String result = null;
        CollectionTerm selectedTerm = this.termsModel.getRowData();
        System.out.println("Row id: " + selectedTerm.getC_id());
        return result;
    }
```

It returns me error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **row is unavailable**

Second question, **how can I display data of selected row on another page?** What I am doing wrong:

```
<h:form id="test">
    <h:outputText value="Id of selected row: " />  
    <h:outputText value="#{dl.c_id}" />
</h:form>
```

Thank you for any help and recommendation! I am a new in JSF, somethimes it is for me very confusing and I can't find any appropriate answer.

JSF Managed Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Register implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private UserDetails user;
    private Term term;
    private CollectionTerm collectionTerm;

    private List<CollectionTerm> dataList;
    private CollectionTerm selectedTerm;
    private TermDataModel termsModel;

    public Register() {

        dataList = new ArrayList<CollectionTerm>();
        loadDataList();
        termsModel = new TermDataModel(dataList);

        user = new UserDetails();
        term = new Term();
        collectionTerm = new CollectionTerm();
    }

    // getters and setters

private void loadDataList() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    dataList = session.createQuery("from CollectionTerm").list();
}

}
```

Data Model

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;

import org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel;

import de.ibmt.upb.model.CollectionTerm;

public class TermDataModel extends ListDataModel<CollectionTerm> implements SelectableDataModel<CollectionTerm> {

    public TermDataModel() {    
    }

    public TermDataModel(List<CollectionTerm> data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public CollectionTerm getRowData(String rowKey) {

        List<CollectionTerm> dataList = (List<CollectionTerm>) getWrappedData();

        for(CollectionTerm term : dataList) {  
            if(term.getC_id().equals(rowKey))  
                return term;  
        } 

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(CollectionTerm term) {
        return term.getC_id();
    }

}
```

JSF

```
<h:form id="collection">
    <p:fieldset legend="Date and time">
        <p:dataTable id="collection" value="#{register.termsModel}" var="dl" selection="#{register.selectedTerm}">
            <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:2%" /> 
            <p:column>
                #{dl.c_id}
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                #{dl.dateCollection}
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                #{dl.timeCollection}
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <p:commandButton value="Save" type="submit" action="#{register.selectData()}" ajax="false" />
     </p:fieldset>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable selection"...">` doesn't need to implement the `productModel`.

**Solution of the above-mentioned problem:** to use a `rowKey`

```
<p:dataTable id="collection" value="#{register.dataList}" var="dl" rowKey="#{dl.c_id}" selection="#{register.selectedTerm}">
    <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:2%" /> 
    <p:column>
        #{dl.c_id}
    </p:column>
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

**How obtain data, e.g. c_id, of selected row:**

```
public String selectData() {
    String result = null;
    System.out.println("Get row data: " + selectedTerm.getC_id());
    return result;
}
```

**How display data of selected row on another page:**

```
<h:form id="test">
    <h:outputText value="Id of selected row: " />  
    <h:outputText value="#{register.selectedTerm.c_id}" />
</h:form>
```